# SML/NJ function error

Tags: smlnj

I want a function that takes a list of integers and returns the list sorted(increasing from left to right). This has to be done by using these two functions:

```
datatype tree=Empty
        | Node of int*tree*tree;
fun treeinsert(Empty,k) = Node(k,Empty,Empty)
  | treeinsert(T as Node(y,left,right),k) =
       if k=y then T
       else if k<y then Node(y,treeinsert(left,k),right)
       else Node(y,left,treeinsert(right,k));

fun inOrder(Empty) = nil
  | inOrder(Node(a,left,right)) =
     inOrder(left)@[a]@inOrder(right) ;
```

So I made this function, which has the problem that allways returns an empty list.

```
val y=Empty;
fun treesort(x::xs)=let val y=treeinsert(Empty,x)
                    in treesort(xs)
                    end
  |treesort []=inOrder(y);
```

What did I do wrong? Thank you in advance..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The variable `y` that you define on line 2 is in scope from the `in` on line 3 until the `end` on line 4. You never use it in that block of code, so the variable is unused and therefore does not affect the behavior of the program (beyond the fact that `treeInsert` is called when you define it). When you use `y` on line 5, this refers to the variable `y` that you defined on line 1 since the other one is not in scope.

It's important to understand that the variable defined on line 1 and the one defined on line 2 are completely independent and only happen to have the same name (meaning that the variable from line 1 can't be accessed while the other one is in scope). Your program is equivalent to this:

```
val y1 = Empty;
fun treesort(x::xs)=let val y2=treeinsert(Empty,x)
                    in treesort(xs)
                    end
  |treesort []=inOrder(y1);
```

This should make it clear why it does not work as you intend.

Comment: So how am I supposed to use the same variable between two "let..in..end" or at least access a "global" from inside a function?

Comment: @user2879198 You can access a global just by writing its name and not defining another variable with the same name anywhere else. I think what you really mean to ask is how you can change the value of a variable. The answer to that is: you can't. You can work around this by using `ref`s (which give you mutable values), but in the vast majority of cases you're better of re-working your program logic, so that you don't have to (usually meaning passing information through additional parameters).

Comment: Could you give me an example of an "appropriate logic" for the fun treesort?

Comment: @user2879198 Define a recursive helper function that takes two parameters: The list (`xs`) and a tree (`y`). When that function recurs, pass the new value for `y` as the argument. Your `treesort` function will then simply be `fun treeseort xs = treesortHelper(xs, Empty)`.

Comment: Ok I found a solution thanks to your advice. Thank you very much for your time!

Answer (score 0):

In this part:

```
let val y=treeinsert(Empty,x)
in treesort(xs)
end
```

what you're returning from the function is `treesort(xs)` but you're not doing anything with `x` or `y` so you'll keep recursing with `xs` until `xs` is `[]` at which point you'll return it.